# Kotlin like selector in Java

Tags: java, kotlin, collections, iterable

I have this code in Kotlin, how do I write it Java?

```
typealias ResolutionSelector = Iterable<Resolution>.() -> Resolution?

/**
 * @return Selector function which always provides the biggest resolution.
 */
fun highestResolution(): ResolutionSelector = { maxBy(Resolution::area) }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To add a custom selector to a list.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi I'm a bit ignorant on Kotlin, could you describe it by words? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well unfortunately Java doesn't have type aliases.
And I think the best you can have is

```
resolutions.stream()
           .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Resolution::getArea));
```

---

`Stream#max` does accept a `Comparator<? super T> comparator`, which you can build ahead of time and then pass as input.

So you could store a *lambda function* such as

```
final Comparator<Resolution> resolutionComparator = (r1, r2) -> /* Comparison logic */;
```

*Edit: the example I had posted with `var` couldn't work, because the compiler couldn't infer the actual type of the variable.*